# How to import Joomla user created date to Drupal?

Tags: users, feeds, datetime, importing-exporting

This new site is migrated from Joomla to Drupal. Most users were created 44 years ago and they should not be. I found out the created date format is different between Joomla and Drupal. So, how can I migrate or convert Joomla created date(something like this "2008-08-05 20:20:42.000000") to Drupal(something like "1335285830")?

---

**Additional information**

PS: I output Joomla Created Date as CSV.

Comment: Drupal uses timestamps. You could convert it to timestamp with `$timestamp = strtotime('2008-08-05 20:20:42.000000');`. Now in `$timestamp` you will have the same output as in Drupal.

Comment: Is there a way I can fix that in CSV file?

Comment: How are you importing?  Migrate?  Feeds?

Comment: Without knowing how you are doing the migration, we cannot answer you. Plus, you accepted an answer talking about using PHP code, and then asked how to do that on a CSV file. If the matter is just changing a text file, then the question is not Drupal-specific.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I can use feeds module to import these data, once I got the output. Right now, most users on this site were created 40 years ago, which should not be like that.

Comment: @MPD I'm going to use the Feeds module.

Comment: I found the answer there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703505/excel-date-to-unix-timestamp